# Cookies, JavaScript, Python, Browsing-but-not-really

Tags: javascript, python, html, cookies

Before, I think I danced around the bush, because I wasn't clear on the ethics of prancing around someone's website with python. I saw one answer on the stackoverflow that was close to what I needed, but it got deleted because ticketmaster.com requested for that to happen.  But, I'll put those reservations aside.

I want to automatically grab a bunch of prices from a grocery store website.  I began my project somewhat new and rusty with python.  I grabbed the URLfiles as a human from my browser sessions and ran a bunch of loops to extract the data I wanted (a lot of '.find').  The problem was, I was, at the time, searching (.find()) the html files which I had downloaded manually.  When I switched my code over to using "urlopen" I ran into a problem I didn't immediately recognize.

This page, for example, shows two different things depending on what your browsing status is.

```
http://www.hannaford.com/thumbnail/Produce/Fruits/pc/28546/46815.uts?displayAll=true
```

And I suppose it ought to, because in a business like this, products and prices could be very sensitive to geography.

My idea has been to start the 'Python-ing' at this page where I already know the store I want to select:
    www.hannaford.com/custserv/store_detail.jsp?viewStoreId=21026

and I have this form in particular:

```
<form action="/custserv/save_user_store.cmd" 
    method="post" name="selectThisStoreForm" 
    onsubmit="return StoreLocator.change.store(this,false,false,21026);"
        >
        <input type='hidden' name='form_state' value='selectThisStoreForm'/>
        <input name="storeId" type="hidden" value="21026"/><p class="browseStoreLink">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
        onclick="this.form.submit();" 
        class="altLink"
        >
        <input class="shopNow" type="image" src="/assets/hf/assets/images/buttons/btn_shopNow.gif" border="0" alt="Shop Now"/>
    </a>
    </p>
</form>
```

So I have the onsubmit sending a JS function to a page that isnt meant to be seen by humans.

Chrome says I have always 10 cookies when I am in a session with hannaford.  7 from "hannaford.com" and 3 from "www.hannaford.com".

So, just flailing a little bit:

```
sesh = requests.Session()
Params = {'selectThisStoreForm':''}
url = "http://www.hannaford.com/custserv/save_user_store.cmd"
sesh.post(url,param=Params)

urlopen(urlFRUITS,cookies=sesh.cookies)#??
```

I am getting cookies out of Sessions.  I am not getting the number of them that Chrome says it does get.  I am also not able to ".find" the tags I want to find in each of these pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `urllib.urlopen` just use `sesh.get([url])`, the cookies will automatically be sent. You are also not sending the right parameters for the form, try:

```
params = { 'form_state' : 'selectThisStoreForm', 'storeid' : '21026' }
sesh.post('http://www.hannaford.com/custserv/save_user_store.cmd', params=params)
resp = sesh.get(urlFRUITS)
```

Alternatively, You could try the `requests` library and the `Session` object, it automatically manages cookies, e.g.:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> r = s.get('http://www.THEWEBSITE.com/custserv/locate_store.cmd')
>>> print r.status_code
200
>>> for c in s.cookies:
>>>     print c
<Cookie JSESSIONID=<ID> for www.THEWEBSITE.com/>
<Cookie PIPELINE_SESSION_ID=<ID> for www.THEWEBSITE.com/>
>>> payload = { 'form_state' : 'selectThisStoreForm', 'storeId' : '62012' } 
>>> r = s.post('http://www.THEWEBSITE.com/custserv/save_user_store.cmd', data=payload)
>>> print r.status_code
200
>>> for c in s.cookies:
>>>    print c
<Cookie JSESSIONID=<ID> for www.THEWEBSITE.com/>
<Cookie PIPELINE_SESSION_ID=<ID> for www.THEWEBSITE.com/>
<Cookie USER_SESSION_VALIDATE_COOKIE=false for www.THEWEBSITE.com/>
```

Without knowing exactly what you are doing, I would try the `requests.Session` object.

Comment: Achampion - that is interesting to me that you know the names of the cookies without knowing the actual website, which tells me I need to spend more time learning how cookies do things and what standards there may be.

Comment: There are numerous shopping/grocery sites that seem to use the same framework, so a quick search on google gave me a site to experiment with. Hopefully this has helped set you in the right direction. I was able to set my store using the above, which is what I assume you are trying to do. And as long as I use the same `session` object then the cookies will be sent along with the requests.

Comment: Sorry I had to take a break from it, but I just came back and I must say "Eureeka" thanks man!  I was able to copy line for line, but I will study it further.  So I just did f ='s.get(...'url or scrape'...).text after that.  Merci Beaucoup